# Limit flex list to visible items

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, air

I want to display a list with itemRenderers in a mobile app but limit the number of displayed items to the number of simultaniously completely displayed items in the list.

This means if the list ist 500px and an itemRenders height 80px I want to display 6 itemRedenderer (and set the lists height to 480px).... If the lists height is 450 px there should be 5 renderer and the lists height setted to 400px.
The ItemRenderers height is setted in css for the renderers class (f.e. MyRendererClass{rendererHeight:80px;}) using media queries depending on device dpi.

Is there any easy way to achive this? Can I get the correct "rendererHeight" value for the current dpi anyhow - as I have no style name to get the StyleDeclaration?

Best regards

Christian

Answer (score 0):

var buttonDeclaration:CSSStyleDeclaration = styleManager.getStyleDeclaration("com.xxx.yyy.itemRenderer.MyItemRenderer");
and
buttonDeclaration.getStyle("rendererHeight");
is working...